# Pass text to UItextfield from UItableViewcell selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to pass text from a `UITableViewCell` selection to a `UITextField`.

I have my `didSelectRowAtIndex` set up like this

```
#pragma mark -- select row
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"%@", selectedCell.textLabel.text);// shows correct values

    currentSelected.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text; // currentSelected is defined below


    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

That is my table view selection, as you can see I am trying to pass the text to the currentSelected `UITextField` however nothing is happening..

This is how I set my currently selected

```
#pragma mark - TextField delegates
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    currentSelected = textField;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma mark - TextField delegates
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    currentSelected = textField;

}
```

replace with below method and make sure textfield delegate is decleared

```
#pragma mark - TextField delegates
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    currentSelected.text = textField.text;

}
```

Comment: This gives me a warning ": Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UITextField *' from 'NSString *'"

Comment: sorry.. textFieldDidEndEditing method

Answer (score 0):

Save the string to a property of your view controller, not to a text field.

Then, once you have the text in a property, you can display it in a text field if you want.

My guess is that in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, currentSelected is nil.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I have done some more work on it and now I am getting the new value to testfieldshouldreturn where i try to set the new text but it dosnt even show up

Comment: any example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @HurkNburkS, what kind of example do you need? Do you not know how to pass a string from one controller to the next?